# What determines max_size in STL containers?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to reproduce the behavior of std::string in C, but there is one thing I don't really know how to do. There is a `max_size` member method that gives the maximum size a string (or any other arrays for vector, etc...) can have, so my question is I know this value can depend of systems, so how do containers determine this number ? And could I get it in C?

Comment: `max_size` defines the maximum size a container theoretically can have for the particular implementation of that container. This number can be way larger than what the OS or hardware can handle.

Comment: I think it's provided by the *allocator*.

Comment: Depending on how faithfully you want to recreate `std::string` you should look into allocators, but it is also possible to implement a string type with a fixed size buffer, then `max_size()` would return the size of this buffer.

Comment: Side note: I think usually `std::basic_string<... char ...>::max_size` is `(SIZE_MAX - 1) / 2`, so that it will fit into "signed `size_t`".

Comment: Then why is it halved? https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h#L918  hm...

Comment: @KamilCuk Hmm, I take that back. I don't know what their thought process is.

Answer (score 5):

> What determines max_size in STL containers?

The implementer of the standard library chooses it. The implementers should design containers to support as large sizes as possible, given the limitations imposed by the API and the target system. The implementation defails of the container, and the supplied allocator may impose additional limitations that should ideally be reflected by a lowered (and thus more accurate) `max_size`.

Note that `max_size` is only rarely useful value in practice. It is a theoretical upper bound that is not necessarily practically reachable... typically because memory isn't sufficient, at least on 64 bit systems. It's used to detect obviously erroneus user input early (and then throw exception accordingly).

> And could I get it in C?

You can define a constant extern variable and initialise it in a c++ translation unit. Example:

```
// common_header.h
// add header guard here
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

extern const size_t cpp_string_max_size;
extern const size_t cpp_vector_int_max_size;

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

// source.cpp
#include "common_header.h"
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

const std::size_t cpp_string_max_size = std::string{}.max_size();
const std::size_t cpp_vector_int_max_size = std::vector<int>{}.max_size();
```

Then, compile the C++ translation unit using a C++ compiler and link it with the C program.

---

> I'm searching for a way that doesn't involve any C++

Depending on what you mean by "any C++", you can use meta-programming: Write a C++ program that produces a C source file that contains constants that were produced by the C++ program. The generation part obviously involves C++, but the generated source will be pure C and can be compiled using only a C compiler.

If this isn't to your liking, you can go read the implementation files of your chosen C++ standard library and see how they have implemented `max_size`, and write the C source manually. This doesn't involve writing or compiling any C++ at any point, although it does involve reading C++.

Comment: Yes, I know it's not useful but I wanted to do it anyway because I want to reproduce as faithfully as possible the behaviour of `std::string` in my C project, even if some of it can be kind of useless, thanks for your response but I'm searching for a way that doesn't involve any C++ and could be complied only with `gcc`

Answer (score 4):

`max_size` defines the maximum size a container theoretically can have for the particular implementation of that container.

That number does not depend on the OS or the available memory but is only given by the implementation of the container.

If **your** (not `std::string` compatible) implementation of a string container is like this:

```
struct string {
   unsigned char size;
   char *data;

   // … further functions …
};
```

Then `max_size` would likely refer to the largest number `unsigned char` can represent.

If your implementation is just a `\0` terminated string, without any other meta information. Then `max_size` might refer to the maximum number of bytes that can be addressed through pointers, for the given target architecture.

So `max_size` just says, the way the container is implemented would be able to handle `max_size` number of elements. But it does not guarantee that the OS is capable of that.

---

For an `std::string` the **upper bounds** of the maximum number of chars the implementation can handle is given by a maximum number of `size_type` and some further constraints.

The [`size_type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string#Member_types) for a `std::string` itself is given by the used allocator (`std::allocator<CharT>`) which defaults to `std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::size_type`.

For a `std::allocator` the `size_type` referees to `std::size_t`.

So for a `std::string` the **upper bound** of `max_size` is the max value of `std::size_t` minus a value `n` that is required to fulfill the other requirements of the string.

The `libstdc++` of `gcc-4.6.2` defines [says this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/libstdc++/api/a00770_source.html#l00721) about the `max_size`:

```
// The maximum number of individual char_type elements of an
// individual string is determined by _S_max_size. This is the
// value that will be returned by max_size().  (Whereas npos
// is the maximum number of bytes the allocator can allocate.)
// If one was to divvy up the theoretical largest size string,
// with a terminating character and m _CharT elements, it'd
// look like this:
// npos = sizeof(_Rep) + (m * sizeof(_CharT)) + sizeof(_CharT)
// Solving for m:
// m = ((npos - sizeof(_Rep))/sizeof(CharT)) - 1
// In addition, this implementation quarters this amount.
static const size_type  _S_max_size;
static const _CharT _S_terminal;
```

and that corresponding [initialization](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/libstdc++/api/a00771_source.html)

```
template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits, typename _Alloc>
  const typename basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::size_type
  basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::
  _Rep::_S_max_size = (((npos - sizeof(_Rep_base))/sizeof(_CharT)) - 1) / 4;
```

According to this [197. max_size() underspecified](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3440.html#197) (not sure if there is any newer update to that), the value of `max_size` won't change from call to call:

> It is clear to the LWG that the value returned by max_size() can't change from call to call.

So you can use the approach of [eerorika](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67196069) to get that value for a specific allocator.

Comment: Methinks it would be less than that due to the std::string::npos requirement.

Comment: @Bathsheba yes could be true. Updated the answer, that the shown string class is not a `std::string` _compatible_ one.

Comment: But `std::string`'s max size is way larger than `UCHAR_MAX` on my system. I printed it and it's `18446744073709551599` while ULLONG_MAX is `18446744073709551615`

Comment: @Fayeure the size depends on the implementation of the stdlib and can vary due to that. I added the information on how the `libstdc++` handles that (the link is to an older source). If you want the actual value for a given implementation you need to solve it like shown in the other answer.